# Xamarin Active Directory using native library, storyboard issue

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin, azure-active-directory

I'm using the Active Directory Authentication Library as found [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) I've then created a binding project in Xamarin and then created some login code to manage logins to our app via ADAL.

Everything was working fine until I moved the app to a Unified app. Ever since doing that when I try to authenticate, I get the following error:

> The required resource bundle could not be loaded. Please read the ADALiOS readme on how to build your application with ADAL provided authentication UI resources.

I have the required storyboards as part of the main iOS app, but for some reason the ADAL library can't seem to find them in the main bundle.

Any insight greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

James, did you try ADAL v3? It supports Xamarin natively, without the need of using bindings against the native ADALs. Although bindings are technically possible, we consider ADAL v3 to be the main way in which we support Xamarin integration.
Please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget/ for an example. ADAL v3 is still in preview, but we are working hard to release it ASAP.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but it exposes an issue we have with a NTLM authentication only being available at certain times of the day. I managed to get around that in code, by making some minor alterations to the objc library.

Comment: So, I guess the question is: is there a way to handle NTLM challenges in the v3 .net library, cos it looks like you have to use the web view only, which is an issue for us?

Comment: NTLM is not supported in V3 .NET library at the moment. We always encourage contribution to the library, so you can check out the Obj-C implementation and contribute to .Net!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, for whatever reason, just adding the Storyboard to the iOS Xamarin project doesn't seem to work any more. If you add the compiled ADALiOS.bundle from the ObjC library to you Xamarin project, it will work.

You add it by selecting add files from folders in Xamarin Studio and selecting the folder directly above the .bundle file in the output tree.

Makes sense I guess.